# Display WooCommerce Regular Price in Table Cell

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price

I'm trying to replace the table cells in the below code with woocommerce regular product price.

I have this code in my functions.php file that adds a pricing table to the content area.

How would I dynamically change the cell (class="pricing-table-full-price") to display the regular product price?

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'insertPricingTable');
function insertPricingTable($content) {
if(is_single() && has_term( 'resin', 'product_cat' ) ) {
  $content.= '<table class="pricing-table">';
  $content.= '<tbody>';
  $content.= '<tr>';
  $content.= '<th>1 - 5</th>';
  $content.= '<th>6 - 11</th>';
  $content.= '<th>12+</th></tr>';
  $content.= '<tr>';
  $content.= '<td class="pricing-table-full-price">Full Price</td>';
  $content.= '<td class="pricing-table-35">35% OFF</td>';
  $content.= '<td class="pricing-table-45">45% OFF</td>';
  $content.= '</tr></tbody></table>';
}
return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you will need somehow to get the product ID you wish to display it's price. In your case, this can be done using the global variable `$post`.

```
    function insertPricingTable($content) {
    if(is_single() && has_term( 'resin', 'product_cat' ) ) {
      global $post;
      $product = new WC_Product($post->ID);
      $product_price = $product->get_price();
      $content.= '<table class="pricing-table">';
      $content.= '<tbody>';
      $content.= '<tr>';
      $content.= '<th>1 - 5</th>';
      $content.= '<th>6 - 11</th>';
      $content.= '<th>12+</th></tr>';
      $content.= '<tr>';
      $content.= '<td class="pricing-table-full-price">'.product_price.'</td>';
      $content.= '<td class="pricing-table-35">35% OFF</td>';
      $content.= '<td class="pricing-table-45">45% OFF</td>';
      $content.= '</tr></tbody></table>';
    }
    return $content;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked out. I slightly modified to use the 35%/45% discount fields using bcmul. Is there a better way to do this?

`$num_str1 = $product_price; 
 $num_str2 = "0.65";
 $scaleVal = 2;
 $resone = bcmul($num_str1, $num_str2, $scaleVal);
 $content.= '<td class="pricing-table-35">'.$resone.'</td>';`